# Dealloc method is not being called in OpenGL ES?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

how to call Dealloc Method in OpenGL ES, because it is not being called itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling the `release` method on the object, There is possibility in which **dealloc** function is not called if your object is either `retained` by **iOS framework**  or your **application** classes.

Comment: @Jhulia, I tried release, but it won't giving 100%, cz many objects are in using again and again, and autorelase also not working as it should.

Comment: @Veer  : read the **memory management for objective -C** rather than **downvoting**, It's an practical thing which i shared with you check your object may be it's retained by some other object in your application. `dealloc` method is only called only if the retainCount on your object is **0** and you call **release** method.

Comment: I did upvote, but I didn't downvote u, and I can't accept answer, yet can't solve problem.

Comment: @Veer:no offense dude ,Not saying to accept but if someone is **downvoting** without knowing concept that's not right .

Comment: I know my memory Jhaliya concepts are bit weaker, but I never do downvote until answer is too much rough, I did upvote u :-)

but solve this problem :-P

Comment: @Veer : it's more of looking into the code and finding the objects of your **opengl** class and check whether they are `deallocated` properly or not,whether they are `retained` or `assigned`, also not put **autorelease** for the objects which you expect  **dealloced** method be called.

Answer (score 0):

dealloc method is called in UIView and also UIViewController. also when you use Open GL application by selecting Open GLEs app tab then you will see there are dealloc method in each class which calls by theselves.
Then i don't think so you are understanding it right.

Comment: Ishu Ji this is my first app on OpenGL, and I am completed project, but it is having some issues of memory, so confused about it, I am removing objects in array, but still objects declared in @interface, I am unable to solve it

Comment: But there is no possibility in which dealloc is not called. Wait for any good answer then and also try to search some solution.